# Create libsvm from multiple csv files for xgboost external memory training

Tags: csv, libsvm, xgboost

I am trying to train an xgboost model using its external memory version, which takes a libsvm file as training set. Right now, all the data is stored in a bunch of csv files which combine together are way larger than the memory I have, say 70G.(you can easily read any one of them). I just wonder how to create one large libsvm file for xgboost. Or if there is any other work round for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you csv files do not have headers you can combine them with the Unix `cat` command.

Example:

```
> ls
file1.csv file2.csv
> cat *.csv > combined.csv
```

Now `combined.csv` is the con**cat**enation of all the other files.

If all your csv files have headers you''ll want to do something trickier, like take the n-1 lines with `tail`.

XGBoost supports [csv as an input.](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_intro.html?highlight=csv)

If you want to convert that to libsvm regardless, you can use [phraug's](https://github.com/zygmuntz/phraug/blob/master/csv2libsvm.py) scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my understand is that libsvm is also a text file. Can I do the same `cat` thing on a bunch of libsvm files?